# Using Google Tag Manager alongside hard-coded Google Analytics tag causes self-referrals

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I've a Google analytics tag setup via google tag manager. Separately I've created a hard coded tag to track transactions. Since adding the hard-coded tag a self referral issue has developed that appears to be related to the attribution of sales. A proportion of sales traffic shows as attributed to a card processing company.

This is the hard coded tag:

```
<script>
ga('create', 'UA-{id-number}-1', {'name': 'eCommerceTrackerUniversal'});
ga('eCommerceTrackerUniversal.require', 'ecommerce');
ga('set', 'hostname', '.domain.com');

ga('eCommerceTrackerUniversal.ecommerce:addTransaction', {
  'id': '{{transactionId}}',
  'revenue': {{transactionTotal}},
  'shipping': {{deliveryCost}}/100
});

ga('eCommerceTrackerUniversal.ecommerce:send');
</script>
```

Can anyone shed any light on the cause of the problem? Am I making a naive mistake in implementing this way? I originally attempted implementing the e-commerce tracking also via google tag manager, but couldn't get it to work.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure but something to think about when you have both GTM and GA installed is the naming of your trackers. GTM and GA use different tracker names so to unify them, you should tell GTM the name of the tracker you use; in your case it would be eCommercceTrackerUniversal. Another thing is your 'set' method isn't using the same tracker name.

Answer (score 1):

Self referrals are often caused by incorrect cookie domains being set.

Although you appear to be attempting to allow the cookie to auto-set itself, why not try setting the correct cookie domain at the point that you create the tracker.  Don't forget the cookie domain should be as high level as possible to ensure you track across sub domains correctly

i.e. your shop might be on shop.domain.com but your checkout process might be on checkout.domain.com.  Make sure you set your cookie domain to .domain.com.

```
ga('create', 'UA-{id-number}-1', {'name': 'eCommerceTrackerUniversal', 'cookieDomain':'.domain.com'});
```

You could of course put this domain in a GTM variable and reference it that way.

Make sure you set the same cookie domain in the GTM native GA tag too.

Out of curiosity, why couldn't you get the native GTM GA ecommerce tag to work?  Seems a bit ridiculous to build a hard coded tag such as this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm trying it out now.

I've built it this way as the dataLayer hasn't been implemented properly for me to use in-built GTM functionality. When I tried building up the e-commerce array myself using javascript, I could get the tag to accept it.

Comment: It's quite common for us to have to leverage non-standard data layers on client sites.  In these cases I always build a custom HTML tag which dynamically pushes the ecommerce data into the DL in the correct format.  This is normally accompanied by a custom event which causes a trigger to  fire an ecommerce tag.  Maybe you want to post your current solution that you tried to build up your ecommerce DL and we could debug that?  It will likely be more beneficial in the long term.

Comment: That sounds like a good way to make progress, I'll dig it up. In the meantime do you think implementing a cross-domain linker might help matters? The site uses two sub-domains rather than two different domains, so not positive that that will help based on GA documentation. If there's any chance that it will solve the problem, it might be a quick sticking plaster though, while we come up with the proper fix.

Comment: Incidentally altering the tag as per your answer didn't fix the problem.

Comment: If you have your GA cookie domain set to the top level domain (e.g. .example.com) then the _ga cookie will persist across all of your sub domains, this will effectively ensure your tracking works across sub domains.  Have a look at the _ga cookie in developer tools and see what domain its set to.  Also assess the _ga cookie value during the user journey and identify at which point it changes (indicating a new user).  This should help you debug the code.

Comment: I'll give that a go. Finding an example of the problem is seemingly challenging though. It's only occurring on 3% of sessions.

Comment: Make sure you check the GA reports for the basics for that 3% first then:  Is there any correlation to device? browser? location?  Did this issue start to appear at a specific point in time?  if so, what happened on that date? new deployment?  etc

Comment: That is helpful, things I tried doing before, but re-visiting seems to have cracked it. The e-commerce tracking wasn't the only thing to change when the problem started, as you cite. Reviewing changes on that day has flagged up a mis-configured event tag and real-time data appears to show a drop off of self-referrals. I'll confirm back here once I've seen it in the server side data.